# Is MVC 3 suitable for a public production site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am about to start a new project and MVC is the way to go because of its simplicity to allow plain request and ajax friendly ones with out the need of web methods.

**Is MVC 3 suitable for a public production site?** Have you encountered any issues at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Is MVC3 Production ready?

**A: ABSOLUTELY.**

My organization has moved absolute 100% of new development to MVC3. We still have webforms and MVC2 sites we support, however all significant new development is being parted out into new MVC3 applications. We then either just join them together with consistent site navigation and bounce between subdomains or use iframes were it makes sense to embed our MVC3 new development into our "legacy" systems (which always amuses me that legacy at my shop still means .NET4 applications, just not MVC3).

Answer (score 2):

I am using mvc 3 right now. It seems to have no issues, in fact it is quite fast.
The only issue we have is architectual ones. Because we are using razor, and razor is version 1.0. In razor there are some weird things you have to do that I do not like. Like how helpers are defined. Other than that it is GREAT.

Answer (score 1):

I think the largest problem I have had with Microsoft's MVC is related to unit testing. The amount of setup code required sometimes makes you shake your head.

That said there are many helpful posts, blogs, helper classes that can ease the learning curve (many on stackoverflow). However, if unit testing isn't a concern to you and microsoft is your tech stack of choice then by all means there is NO reason why it would not be suitable for a production site.